# Vouchers not reflecting in Ecommerce Website even after adding via back office admin

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

I have created a voucher through Catalogue -> Discount for a specific user.
But this voucher is not reflecting in the My Account Section of that user.

[image]

Comment: The voucher is enabled?, have you defined a code?, have quantities available?, as you can see, its difficult to identify the cause without see all the configuration of the voucher.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I resolved this as this was due to time difference between hosting servers